# Cloud Object Storage Cannot be detected/identified/attached when creating a new project within IBM Cloud Pak for Data

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-pak-for-data

I am working with a Lite plan of IBM Cloud. Although I have an active Cloud Object Storage (COS) instance, the Cloud Pak for Data cannot detect/identify/attached it when I tried to create a new project. I clicked "refresh", deleted the active COS instance and created a new one, but the problem remains. Any clues about how to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJWsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue however if I switch account or if I switch to a different data center (from Dallas to Frankfurt), the issue doesn't occur anymore.
This is as of Septembre 2023.

Continuing my research. I found the following page in the documentation:
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/console/wdp_admin_cos.html?context=cpdaas#cos-delegation
I went through. I updated my user profile. I have both locations : Global and Dallas. I have also checked the resource groups associated with my user profile. I have selected all resource groups. The resource group to which the COS instance was associated was already checked, nonetheless I checked all resource groups.
After doing this update, I was able to create a new project and pick the COS instance (Lite plan) associated with this Cloud Pak for Data in this account , in this datacenter.
I guess I might have been lucky. I just wanted to share my luck here.
Julien